# Unreliable sockets behavior on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets, client-server, packet

I am trying to implement remote resource loading in my iOS game, just for developing purposes. All the artists work with PCs and we just have one Mac ( which I use to code ), so when they make changes, they need to stop my work just to see them in the device ( they can see the changes in PC, but finally they have to be checked on the device ). That's the reason I want to try this.

I have implemented the server and the client successfully ( using TCP protocol and sending the files in chunks of 64KB ), but it just works in the iPhone Simulator and PC ( the Mac is using the same WiFi connection as the iPhone ). I started using the same code for connection in both platforms ( using BSD sockets ), but after trying everything I had in my head to fix that on the iPhone, I implemented the connection part in iPhone using CFStream, because I read somewhere that using BSD sockets doesn't switch on the network. Despite the result was a bit better ( the load went farther ), it failed too.

In my method to send data, I'm aware that the OS doesn't have to send it all, so I have to keep a loop until all my data is sent. The same for receiving data. So I don't think this is the problem.

When I say that all of this fails, I mean that the iPhone gets locked forever inside a 'recv', and sometimes it doesn't even connect to the server ( using 'connect' or 'CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost' ). Adding more to the party, when it gets locked on 'connect', if I put a breakpoint after the 'connect' call, the debugger stops my program there and I can continue from there ( although the program gets locked in some random 'recv' ).

I'm not an expert with network programming, so I don't discard the option that I don't understand the 'reliable' part of the TCP protocol, and maybe I lose some packet, and that's the reason that the iPhone gets locked inside a 'recv' ( but this theory doesn't explain why 'connect' fails sometimes ).

By the way, I'm using WinSock 2.2 on Windows 7 64-bits, and iOS 4.2 on an iPod 4.

Sorry for writing such a long post. I don't post any code because I fell it will be too long, but if you think is necessary, please tell my and I will.

Thanks a lot,
Carlos

EDIT: I think is important to say that I don't use multiple threads for this purpose in iPhone, and the sockets are blocking ( well, at least I don't explicitly put them in non-blocking state. My understanding is that they are blocking by default )

EDIT 2: Ok, let's put some code =)

```
bool CTCPStream::connect( const CNetIP &ipDestination, uint32_t port ) {    
    CFStringRef host = CFStringCreateWithCString( kCFAllocatorDefault, ipDestination.toString( ).c_str( ), kCFStringEncodingASCII );//CFSTR( "192.168.1.99" );
    UInt32 p = port;

    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost( kCFAllocatorDefault, host, p, &_readStream, &_writeStream );
    if( !_readStream || !_writeStream ) {
        close( );
        return false;
    }

    if( !CFWriteStreamOpen( _writeStream ) || !CFReadStreamOpen( _readStream ) ) {
        close( );
        return false;
    }

    CFReadStreamSetProperty( _readStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue );
    CFWriteStreamSetProperty( _writeStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue );

    return true;
}

boost::optional< uint32_t > CTCPStream::sendBytes( const void *ptr, uint32_t size ) const {
    const UInt8 *source = reinterpret_cast< const UInt8* >( ptr );

    uint32_t bytesSent = 0;
    while( size ) {
        int bytes = CFWriteStreamWrite( _writeStream, &source[ bytesSent ], size );
        if( bytes == -1 )
            return boost::optional< uint32_t >( );

        size -= bytes;
        bytesSent += bytes;
    }

    return bytesSent;
}

boost::optional< uint32_t > CTCPStream::recvBytes( void *ptr, uint32_t size ) const {
    GASSERT( isConnected( ) );
    GASSERT( size );

    UInt8 *target = reinterpret_cast< UInt8* >( ptr );

    uint32_t bytesRead = 0;
    while( size ) {
        int bytes = CFReadStreamRead( _readStream, &target[ bytesRead ], size );
        if( bytes == -1 )
            return boost::optional< uint32_t >( );

        size -= bytes;
        bytesRead += bytes;
    }

    return bytesRead;
}
```

And there is not much more of it. At the beginning of the iPhone App I do a 'connect' ( which sometimes fails, as commented before ) and I start doing send's and recv's, without doing any acknowledge ( my understanding is that TCP handles that ).

The server part is a typical listener socket with a thread for a blocking 'accept'. I don't put this code because I don't want to bloat the post and I think this part works fine.

EDIT 3: I have created an Ad-Hoc network and connected directly my iPod with my Windows 7 PC, and it worked perfectly. These are good news for me, but I'm still worried, because I would like to not rely on having to create an Ad-Hoc network. Can the problem be in the router? I'm pretty lost in this subject.

Comment: By the description of your problem it looks like you used an approach with at least one OSX-only (or iOS 5.0 only) function. It 'compiles' ok but doesn't function properly on an iOS device. Posting code for creating streams and connecting to server might be a good idea.